# Can't add lists together - “TypeError:float' object is not subscriptable”

Tags: python, list, typeerror

Can't figure out exactly why, but this code works exactly as intended until I try to print `test2` which leads to a `TypeError: float' object is not subscriptable`. It doesn't seem to matter what kind of math I do or the contents of `test`, I still get the same error.

Problem code:

```
with open("InputFileData.csv") as file:
   SampleTotalHours = file.readlines();

TotalHours = []

for element in SampleTotalHours:
   hoursAsStrings = element.split(',')
   hoursAsFloats = [float(hourString) for hourString in hoursAsStrings]
   TotalHours.append(sum(hoursAsFloats))

EmployeeNumber = 4
i = 0

TotalHoursInt = []
TotalHoursInt = TotalHours

test = [11, 12, 13]
test2 = TotalHoursInt[1] + test[1]
print(test2[1])
```

Contents "InputFileData.csv":

```
40.1,39.7,40,38
36,36,35.5,35.8
40,41.6,40.3,40
20.4,22.8,20,20
```

Output:

```
TypeError:float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: maybe easier consider using [csv.reader()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `test2` is a floating value not a list, and you are printing 2nd index of a variable which is incorrect,
so just write

```
print(test2)
```

this should give you proper ans